# Closing apps with no start bar

Tags: apps, windows-10-mobile, navigation-key

I recently purchased a Lumia 550 and all is going well.

I am struggling with closing apps as on a lot of the apps I have, the start bar is hidden and un-un-hidable within the app.

How can I get back to the start screen from this without opening the notification centre and going to camera, then hitting the start button when it appears?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by start bar? Are you asking about how to close the apps or how to go to the start screen from the app?

Comment: Yes, the little black bar with the back button, start button, and search button.

Comment: I'm trying to get to the start screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swipe up from the bottom of the screen to open the navigation bar.

The start bar you are referring to is popularly known as navigation bar.

You can see the offical [Microsoft document](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/getstarted-buttons-mobile) here which says,

> On phones without built-in buttons, reveal the navigation bar by
>   putting a finger below the screen and swiping up.